# iOS / Flutter: You don’t have permission to save the file “flutter_callback_cache.json"

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I get stuck in splash screen after restore app data (use replace container in Xcode)
But it's not always stuck, sometime it work, sometime not.
Here is error log detail, many thanks for your helping:

```
Error excluding flutter_callback_cache.json from backup Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “flutter_callback_cache.json” in the folder “Caches”." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/81868F99-BCC1-42A8-B322-68D859C4FA97/Library/Caches//flutter_callback_cache.json, NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/81868F99-BCC1-42A8-B322-68D859C4FA97/Library/Caches//flutter_callback_cache.json, NSUnderlyingError=0x282b6afd0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"}}
[ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/darwin/graphics/FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(42)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(open_failed /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/81868F99-BCC1-42A8-B322-68D859C4FA97/Documents/an_yen_v2.db)
#0      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.openDatabase (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:793)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.doOpen (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:907)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      SqfliteDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase (package:sqflite_common/src/database.dart:46)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.openDatabase.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite_common/src/factory_mixin.dart:112)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      ReentrantLock.synchronized.<anonymous closure> (package:synchronized/src/reentrant_lock.dart:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33)
<<…>
```

I've tried uninstall app and try replace container again, didn't work!